# Microsoft.AspNetCore.All on .NET Framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want use ASP NET Core 2.0 (and also EF Core 2.0) on .NET Framework 4.6.1.

On [Microsoft's announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/14/announcing-asp-net-core-2-0/), it's OK.

But the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is only for .NET CoreApp 2.0 not for .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` its for .NET Core, not for .NET Classic.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` is just a metapackage, it includes nothing but references to other packages and is only intended to be used with .NET Core 2.0 applications which can use the new runtime stores.

Include the regular ASP.NET Core 2.0 packages instead of the `.All` package and you should be fine.

If you need more info about runtime stores, you can read about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/25/asp-net-core-2-0-features-1/).